# Select Records with Unique Combinations of Fields in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

In Meteor.js, how can we select unique combination of fields? For example, if we have:

```
type    color    owner
----    -----    -----
animal  red      paul
animal  red      jack
animal  blue     paul
food    blue    jack
```

what should be done to get the following result set:

```
type    color 
----    ----- 
animal  red
animal  blue
food    blue
```

I'm using `meteor-smart-collections` 0.4.0 and Meteor 0.7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore to do this fairly easily if you're prepared to do a `fetch()`, which probably depends on how many documents you've got:

```
_.uniq(yourCollection.find({}, {fields: {type: 1, color: 1, _id: 0}}).fetch(), function(item) { return item.type+item.color; });
```

The only word of warning is that you're concatenating strings for the purposes of comparison, so it would fail if there was any possibility of pairs like `{type: 'foo', color: 'bar'}` and `{type: 'foob', color: 'ar'}`.  This doesn't seem to be likely in the example you give, but if you're concerned about it being a problem you would just need to change the structure of the iterator function to do something a bit more imaginative than concatenating the two fields.  It needs to return a primitive though, I don't think it'll work if you return an object or an array.

Comment: A better function might be `function(item) { return JSON.stringify({ type: item.type, color: item.color }); }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Meteor's Minimongo driver includes a helper for the Aggregation Framework yet, however there are [suggestions on how to call the underlying MongoDB `aggregate` command](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/644) on at least one of the issues.

Assuming your data looks like:

```
db.things.insert([
    { type: 'animal', color: 'red',  owner: 'paul'},
    { type: 'animal', color: 'red',  owner: 'jack'},
    { type: 'animal', color: 'blue', owner: 'paul'},
    { type: 'food',   color: 'blue', owner: 'jack'}
])
```

You can do this grouping on the server side using MongoDB's [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) and the [`$group` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.things.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: { type: "$type", color: "$color" }
    }}
)
```

The results would look like:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "type" : "food",
                "color" : "blue"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "type" : "animal",
                "color" : "blue"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "type" : "animal",
                "color" : "red"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```